# Any approach to peek memory data structure of C/CPP application?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-management

... like how many memory consumed by what / how many objects, as in JVM heap dump file. Our service process is consuming remarkable memory, which is being complained by others living in a same OS.

The applications structure is weird, it leveraged reverse JNI to call java interface from c++ code, also it's a network application, all these make it almost impossible to use tools like valgrind or purify.

Any suggestion would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overload new/delete and track memory usage that way.

Comment: Considering the explicit mention of reverse JNI, this won't help at all.

Comment: Thank Graham, another problem shows up tho, seems the overloaded new/delete operators cannot be declared within a name space, in that case how could the application see them in their own name space?

Comment: @MSalters: It seemed to me that unknown was allocating memory in C++ and then passing those objects to the Java process.